# Lost session when refresh page in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, frameworks, laravel-5

I have a problem with login in Laravel 5.2. I'm using `make:auth` to create login. When refreshing sometime or directed to some another pages, the `auth()::user->name` lost, then I must login again. How can I fix this bug?

Comment: do you run other web application (laravel) with same hostname (localhost) in your browser? If your Auth is working fine and you have put your page route to pass the Auth route middleware then everything good, Problem may be something else not the App.

Comment: thanks you, i solved it.